# NSString componentsSeparatedByString "&" but ignore "& amp;"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Need to separate a string on `&` but not on `&amp;`.

Is there a more elegant way to code this up rather than just replacing it first then separating it on the `&`?  Like this...

```
query = [query stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"~~~"];
NSArray * kvpairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

NSMutableArray *mArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *kvp in kvpairs) {
    [mArr addObject:[kvp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~~~" withString:@"&amp;"]];
}
kvpairs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mArr];
[mArr release];
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? What happens when a component begins with “amp;”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to enumerate through the string on a regular expression that matches `&` but not `&amp;`, e.g.: `@"&(?!amp;)"`. This will be more cumbersome than your current method but more exact, because it will work without modifying the original string and doesn't rely on a token value.

If you control the input to this method and can guarantee that `~~~` won't appear normally, there's nothing wrong with using `~~~`. However if you *don't* control the input then you should attempt to parse the string without modification.

Comment: It won't be all that cumbersome. You just do `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` and grab everything that isn't in those ranges. It should be roughly the same length as the OP's code.

Comment: @Chuck: You're quite right... I assumed it would be a little more cumbersome only because I think you'd have to keep an index of the last match's offset (and length) so you'd know where to slice the string on each match. It's not that much work as you say.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything wrong with that, as long as you are 100% sure that the string `~~~` won't occur in your query.

If you are not, my next step would be to implement a method to parse the string into an array.  In this method, you could find each &, then check if it is followed by amp;.  If it is, move on to the next one, if it is not, cut the string there and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

HTML entities and references are really not a good thing to have hanging around in URLs. Unless there is a **very** good reason that HTML entities **must** be used, I would recommend using '%26' in the URL encode an ampersand.

That being said, you will run into problems if '&' is not the only HTML entity or reference, so unless you are absolutely sure '&' is the only one, you will need a more robust solution.